# Can RediSearch return the property of found array item when indexing JSON arrays?

Tags: arrays, database, indexing, redis, full-text-search

I have groups of entities saved in a Redis database. Each group is its own JSON-type key (let's say for a simple example it's a list of users, `userlist:1`, `userlist:2`), and each value has an array of objects, like so:

```
"name": "accounting_team",
"people": [
    {
        "name": "Ahmed",
        "email: "ahmed@some.domain"
    },
    {
        "name": "Boris",
        "email": "boris@some.domain"
    }
]
```

I need to create an index that would search a property of the objects in the array, and return:

1. the database key (in this example, the `userlist:N` key name)
2. *a specific property of the found object* (let's say in this example, the name associated with the email)

Indexing using `FT.CREATE` works as expected: `FT.CREATE nameSearch ON JSON PREFIX 1 userlist: SCHEMA $.people.*.email AS userEmail TAG` indexes all the emails, so searching with `FT.SEARCH nameSearch '@userEmail:{ahmed\@some\.domain}'` or (`boris\@some\.domain}`) returns the needed key `userlist:1`, and its full contents.

However, I cannot find a way to return a property of the found object. In this example, searching `FT.SEARCH nameSearch '@userEmail:{boris\@some\.domain}' RETURN 1 $.people.*.email` returns `Ahmed` instead of `Boris`. I guess this is because the `*` operator in the JSONPath doesn't specify an index, but rather "any value", so it gives first value it encouters.

Is there a way to `RETURN` directly a property (in this exmaple, the specific `name` value of object where the `email` value was found)? Or at least, is it possible to `RETURN` the found index in the array?

Comment: Have you tried using DIALECT 3? It’s more suitable for multi-value querying

Comment: @A.Guy If I understand correctly, that's SQL? Since the whole database atm is a document store, I haven't considered using it. However, maybe a relational model is better suited for such a use case. I'm not so well informed on the differences in workflow, if you would like to explain more, I would be curious to find out.

Comment: No. I'm talking about `DIALECT` parameter of RediSearch. https://redis.io/commands/ft.search/ at the return section.

Comment: from the Docs:

Return multiple values.
When the index is defined ON JSON, a reply for a single attribute or a single JSONPath may return multiple values when the JSONPath matches multiple values, or when the JSONPath matches an array.
Prior to RediSearch v2.6, only the first of the matched values was returned. Starting with RediSearch v2.6, all values are returned, wrapped with a top-level array.
In order to maintain backward compatibility, the default behavior with RediSearch v2.6 is to return only the first value.
To return all the values, use DIALECT 3 (or greater, when available).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSONPath filter expressions `?()` turned out to give the needed result. They can be used to iterate through all array values when placed inside `[]`, and the `@` symbol is used for "current index that's being iterated". The path can be specified in the return statement.

So a search like `FT.SEARCH nameSearch '@userEmail:{boris\@some\.domain}' RETURN 1 "$.people[?(@.userEmail=='boris\@some\.domain')].name"` will return `"Boris"`.

Several things to note:

- The path needs to be in quotes
- The compared value needs to be in quotes if it's a string (different ones from the path, so if path is enclosed in `""`, enclose email in `''`)